# Bash: Remove unique and keep duplicate

Tags: bash, sorting

I have a large file with 100k lines and about 22 columns. I would like to remove all lines in which the content in **column 15** only appears once. So as far as I understand its the reverse of

```
sort -u file.txt
```

After the lines that are unique in column 15 are removed, I would like to shuffle all lines again, so nothing is sorted. For this I would use

```
shuf file.txt
```

The resulting file should include only lines that have at least one duplicate (in column 15) but are in a random order.

I have tried to work around sort -u but it only sorts out the unique lines and discards the actual duplicates I need. However, not only do I need the unique lines removed, I also want to keep every line of a duplicate, not just one representitive for a duplicate.

Thank you.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1107659

Comment: Bash has no built-in capabilities for sort. The `sort` command is provided by your operating system, and differs from system to system. Check `man sort` on your system to see what options are available. And for your particular problem, consider using a more advanced tool like `awk` or `perl` to handle complexities like splitting content by "column".

Comment: Redirect the results of your unique sort on col 15 to a temp file, the `grep -vf temp original` to remove the unique line from the original file. Check if your `sort` supports `--key=KEYDEF` and create a `KEYDEF` to sort on col 15.

Comment: You can use `uniq -d` to get all the duplicated values in a sorted input stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `uniq -d` to get a list of all the duplicate values, then filter the file so only those lines are included.

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR { dup[$0]; next; } 
     $15 in dup' <(awk -F'\t' '{print $15}' file.txt | sort | uniq -d) file.txt > newfile.txt
```

`awk '{print $15}' file.txt | sort | uniq -d` returns a list of all the duplicate values in column 15.

The `NR==FNR` line in the first `awk` script turns this into an associative array.

The second line processes `file.txt` and prints any lines where column 15 is in the array.

Comment: Thank you! It seems to work, however one thing that isnt making sense to me. Just to check if all unique strings were removed, I ran sort -t$'\t' -k15 -u file.txt > uniq and when I check the number of lines it gives me about 1300 more lines that are still included when I run your neat command.

Comment: `-k15` should be `-k15,15`. Otherwise it means the key is all fields from 15 to the end.

Comment: Okay! So now there are still 600 lines more sorted out as uniq when I run the sort command compared to your command. Would you have an idea why?

Comment: Can you post some sample input that produces the problem?

Comment: Are there spaces in some of the fields? `awk` uses any whitespace as the field delimiter by default, use `-F'\t'` if it should only use tab.

Comment: It seems you already included that in your code? Not sure if its cool to share via drive? This is the file I am using.https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jhpQwqtzLE3b2555Q_1I99ket3DcaMxS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: How would I include `-F'\t'` differently from how it is in the `awk` command you have written?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, why would it need to be different? I added that to the code after your comment made it clear that the fields are tab-separated.

Comment: I don't want to process 100k lines. Can you post a small sample in the question and show the difference between what you want and what you're getting instead?

Answer (score 0):

Short version

```
awk '{if (seen[$15]++)print $0}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`3`, `5`, and `6` are properly excluded from the output, no pre-sorting required, but output ordering not guaranteed to mirror input ordering ::

-- change `$(_ = 1)` to `$(_ = 15)`

---

```
echo '4
4
2
17
2
4
12
6
3
7
13
11
7
10
10
13
5
11
2
11' | gtee >( gsort -n | uniq -c >&2; ) | gcat -
```

---

```
   3 2
   1 3
   3 4
   1 5
   1 6
   2 7
   2 10
   3 11
```

---

```
mawk '(__ = ___[$(_ = 1)])=="" ? \
      (NF =(___[$_] = $!_)<__) : __==(____ = "\6") || 
               ($!_ = __ ORS $!_)^(___[$_] = ____)'
```

---

```
 1  4
 2  4
 3  2
 4  2
 5  4
 6  7
 7  7
 8  10
 9  10
10  13
11  13
12  11
13  11
14  2
15  11
```